# If/Else in .map function react

Tags: reactjs

i have a question . I have to build an app where people can search  for music from "lastFm" . So far so good , i already made few things to works normal , but i have a problem with if/else in map function , i've try to show user "no result found" if there are any , but with no luck .If there is 1+ results , will be displayed on the screen , but if there are any , nothing happen . Here is my code .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

import {
  TextField,
  Button,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemAvatar,
  ListItemText,
  Avatar,
  Card,
  CardContent
} from '@material-ui/core';
import axios from 'axios';

import './App.css';

const API_URL = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?limit=5&format=json&method=artist.search&api_key=' + process.env.REACT_APP_LASTFM_APPKEY;

const isEmpty = (str) => str.length === 0;
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
    savedArtists: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const existing = localStorage.getItem('savedArtists')
    if (existing) {
      this.setState({ savedArtists: JSON.parse(existing) })
    }
  }

  onTextChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({ searchTerm: value });
  }

  search = (terms) => {
    const request = API_URL + '&artist=' + terms;

    axios.get(request).then((response) => {
      const results = response.data.results;
      const artists = results.artistmatches.artist.map((artist) => {
        const avatarImage = artist.image.find(image => image.size === 'medium');
        const imageUrl = avatarImage['#text'];
        return { ...artist, avatar: imageUrl }
      });

      this.setState({ artists });
    })
  }

  onSearchClick = () => {
    this.search(this.state.searchTerm);
  }

  clearSearch = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchTerm: '',
      artists: []
    })
  }

  onResultClick = (artist) => {
    this.clearSearch();
    const savedArtists = this.state.savedArtists;
    savedArtists.push(artist)
    this.setState({ savedArtists: savedArtists })
    localStorage.setItem('savedArtists', JSON.stringify(savedArtists));
  }

  render() {
    const results = this.state.artists || [];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
            <Toolbar className="search-bar">
              <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
                Photos
              </Typography>
              <TextField
                placeholder="Search on Last.fm"
                className="search-input"
                onChange={this.onTextChange}
                value={this.state.searchTerm}
              />
              <Button
                onClick={this.onSearchClick}
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                disabled={isEmpty(this.state.searchTerm)}
              >
                Search
              </Button>
              {!isEmpty(this.state.searchTerm) && (
                <Button
                  onClick={this.clearSearch}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Clear
                </Button>)
              }
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </header>
//****Here is  where i've try to use if/else
        <List className="search-results">
          {
            results.map((artist ,results) => {
              if(results.length === 0)

              return (<ListItem> Not Found</ListItem>

              ); else {
                return (                <ListItem
                  button
                  key={artist.name}
                  className="result"
                  onClick={() => this.onResultClick(artist)}
                >
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar src={artist.avatar} alt={artist.name} />
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText primary={artist.name} />
                  <Button
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="secondary"
                    size="small"
                    className="add-button"
                  >
                    Add to favorites
                  </Button>
                </ListItem>);
              }


            })

          }
        </List>
        <div className="artist-container">
          {
            this.state.savedArtists.map((artist, i) => {
              return (
                <Card className="artist-card"
                  key={i}
                >
                  <CardContent>
                    {artist.name}
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to do an if/else in the map of the array. But if the array has no items, then there is nothing to map.

What to do is to use a ternary to check if the array has any results:

```
{ results && result.length ? 
    <List className="search-results">
            {
                results.map((artist) => {
                    return ( 
                    <ListItem button key={artist.name} className="result" onClick={() => this.onResultClick(artist)} >
                        <ListItemAvatar>
                            <Avatar src={artist.avatar} alt={artist.name} />
                        </ListItemAvatar>
                        <ListItemText primary={artist.name} />
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            color="secondary"
                            size="small"
                            className="add-button"
                        >
                            Add to favorites
                        </Button>
                    </ListItem>
                    );
                })
            }
    </List>
    : <div>No Results</div>
}
```

Here, we're checking if `results.length` is considered truthy or not, if it's 1 or higher, then it will render your list, otherwise it will render our `div` informing the user there is no results, which you can change out to be whatever you want.

Comment: yeah , it worked , but i want to display 'no results' only when user click on "search"

Comment: A quick and dirty solution to that would be to add something to state like `searched` which is a boolean that is set to true after the user searches, then check for that in the ternary by making it `(results && result.length) || !this.state.searched`. 

There are probably much nicer ways of doing it however.

Comment: i'll try this . Ty

Answer (score 1):

You're having an error there. It's `.map(result: any, index: number, original: [])`, so you're referring to an index number with argument `results`:

```
results.map((artist, results) => {
  if(results.length === 0) { ... }
});
```

So fix it just by not referring to `results` as a argument of `.map`